# scikit learn + random forest segmentation

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, image-segmentation

I am using random forest function in scikit learn for segmentation of image.
However i am not able to create an input to the function clf.fit(X,Y).
X is a training matrix of (n_samples,n_features), Y is a target matrix of (n_samples,) in which the last attribute is the labels of the target class.
I want to train 50 images with four-five features, like HOG features,RGB features,f17 filter and texon map.

Can anyone please help me create  the matrix X and Y.
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a RandomForestClassifier to classify pixel-wise for your segmentation? You need to be more specific about what your doing, and add some example code.

Comment: Just to give you an idea. You usually need 1000s of images to train something really simple like recognizing black digits on a black background. With only 50 images you won't get meaningful results. And a feature for an image is one pixel. Meaning a 50x50 pixel with rgb has 750 features.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just classifying each pixel on its own, just put the rgb values into X and the segment as Y.

Something likely better though would be to pick a small region around the pixel, and either use near neighbors rgb values - all concated from left to right in each row, or the distributions of each of r,g,b within a local region.